# how do I pass a date in text format to DATE format with sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called sale where I have a field that saves the date DD / MM / YYYY the type of this field is text now that I need to make filters with that date I have had problems with consulting the information well, as I understand the idea is that field was as DATE.

I would like to know what is the ideal way to be able to pass this field to DATE and put the correct format YYYY-MM-DD I do not know if the same field can be updated to create another field called venta_at where the date is saved with the DATE format .

```
UPDATE "sale" SET "sale.sale_date" = 
  CAST( SUBSTRING ( "sale_at", 7, 4 ) ¦¦ '-' ¦¦ 
        SUBSTRING ( "sale_at", 4, 2 ) ¦¦ '-' ¦¦ 
        SUBSTRING ( "sale_at", 1, 2 )  
           AS DATE)
```

executing this throws me an error

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"sale" SET "sale.sell_date" =

CAST (SUBSTRING ("venta_at", 7, 4) Â¦Â¦ 'at line 1

Comment: Please share more details. Additionally, please check how you should quote table names - or does that table `venta` contain a colum named `venta.venta_fecha` (containing that dot)?

Comment: "venta" is a string. Perhaps you meant   \`venta\`

Comment: yes venta is sale in spanish is string type text

Comment: Its the quoting, not the word meaning that @Strawberry is highlighting. [date functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) should be used on dates rather than treating them as strings.

Comment: yes but it is an old database and I don't want to lose that information

Comment: BTW || is a shortcut for OR in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using: [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
UPDATE venta SET sale.sale_date =  STR_TO_DATE(sale_at, "%d / %m / %Y")
```

Comment: UPDATE venta SET venta.venta_at =  STR_TO_DATE(venta.venta_fecha, "%d / %m / %Y")